# Boxing a number and aligning it vertically along the baseline

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I am making a big list of exercises and I'd like to box the number of the exercise at each line.

I found this:

```
\tikzstyle{square}=[minimum width=0.5cm,
  minimum height=0.3cm,
  rectangle,
  rounded corners=1pt,
  draw,
  text=Blue,
  font=\bfseries]

  \newcommand{\square}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture} \node[square] (N) at (0,0) {\bfseries $#1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

  \square{345} bla bla bla
```

I am almost satisfied but the square is not aligned with my `bla bla bla`.

How can I get the box aligned?

Comment: Hi Damien, please could you provide a small compilable `.tex` file, so I can easily reproduce your problem on my machine?

Comment: \fbox{\textcolor{blue}{345}} blah blah blah

Comment: Add `baseline=(N.base)` as option to the `tikzpicture`

Comment: BTW: IIRC `\tikzstyle{square}=[...]` is deprecated and `\tikzset{square/.style={...}}` should be used instead.

Comment: I tried \ovalbox, but the result is not as nice as with tikz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine `anchor=base` and the `baseline` option (no need to name the node).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\tikzset{square/.style={
  minimum width=0.5cm,
  minimum height=0.3cm,
  shape=rectangle,
  rounded corners=1pt,
  draw,
  text=blue,
  font=\boldmath,
  anchor=base}}
\newcommand*{\square}[2][]{\tikz[baseline]{\node[square,#1] {$#2$};}}
\begin{document}
\square{345} bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I have to say, the 15 character limit on comments is TOTAL BS.

Comment: See the above comment circumvents the 15 character limit, and is more useless than almost anything!

Comment: Yep, really nice…

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}


\begin{document}

{\colorbox{yellow}{345}} - blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]