# How can I draw oval circle around a string?

Tags: strings, circles

How can I draw oval circle around a string? For example, when I have "1,3,4,6", how can I put them in a circle?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103557/size-of-tikz-ellipse-node

Comment: You can use any of the methods provided in [Putting a coloured background behind text without adding whitespace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88977/5764) or [How to specify a fill color in RGB format in a node in tikzpicture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24434/5764)

Comment: Here is another related question: [Boxing a number and aligning it vertically along the baseline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114685) You can use every shape of TikZ of course. Your example resembles the `rounded rectangle` shape from the `shapes.misc` library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `shapes.misc` library offers the `rounded rectangle` shape. You can also use the `shadows` library to add shadows.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(char.base)]
\node(char)[draw,fill=white,
  shape=rounded rectangle,
  drop shadow={opacity=.5,shadow xshift=0pt},
  minimum width=1.8cm]
  {1,3,4,6};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I found this code works fine with me.

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\mymk}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=south west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=7mm,
    text height=2mm](char){\ensuremath{#1}} ;}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

Hello, \mymk{1,2,3,4,5} world \circled{1}
```

[image]

Refer to [How to draw a circle around text](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1152http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1152) and [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers).

Comment: it'd be great if you could reference your source

Comment: @cmhughes: updated my answer.

Comment: You can control the "roundedness" of the corners by passing values to `rounded corners`. For example, `rounded corners=10pt` would produce a shape more closely resembling the one in your question.

Comment: Using `DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `newcommand` was necessary for me to make it work with some bibtex / backref commands.

Answer (score 5):

Just for comparison, here is a ConTeXt solution:

```
\defineframed
    [roundframed]
    [
      corner=round,
      location=low,
      loffset=0.1em,
      roffset=0.1em,
    ]

\starttext

Hello \roundframed{1,2,3,4} world.

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I don't have the ability to add comments on the TeX site yet. You can look at the thread dustin mentioned. Alternatively, you can use a box: `$\boxed{1,3,4,6}$`, which will appear:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to comment if you have solution to propose.  Can you make your solution compilable though and add the output image?

Comment: I think the poster wants a flat edges above and below the string and then rounded sides.

Comment: Ah, then, I think your link would work better. Thanks for edit, by the way! I don't have the ability to post images yet.

Comment: Just post links and someone will change it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution using `tcolorbox`...

```
   \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \begin{document}
    \tcbox[enhanced,drop shadow,colback=white]{\Large 1,2,3,4}
    \end{document}
```

The out put is..
[image]